# How to add same values to different keys in dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have 2 JSON files. 1 file with the the student numbers and 1 file with the students.

I have a list of dictionaries with the name, e-mail, and student number of students.

What I want to do is if there are 60 students I want to give them a unique student number. That part is working in the elif statement. The part which I dont know how to implement is:

If there are 20 students, I want to give for example 2 students the same studentnumber(which sounds stupid but I need it). In this case the student is the key and studentnumber is the value.

What I have now:

```
# student
[{"Student1":029182,"e-mail":"example@.com"},{"Student2":0591238,"e-mail":"example@.com"},{"Student3":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com"}]



studentnumbers = [{"studentnumber":"029182","ID":0},{"studentnumber":"0591238","ID":1},{"studentnumber":"9213189","ID":2}]

students = [list(data.values())[0] for data in studentnumbers]


ID = 0
# students is a list of studentnumbers
if len(students) <= 20:
    # studentInfo is my dictionary with the key and values
    for data in studentnumbers:
        try:
            pass

        except IndexError:
            pass



elif len(students) <= 60:
    for data in studentnumbers:
        try:   
            studentnumbers[ID] = students[ID]
            ID += 1
            break
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print("..")
else:
    print("...")

with open('Students.json','w') as instudent:
    json.dump(studentnumbers,instudent,indent=2)
```

output what I have now:

```
[{"Student1":029182,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":029182},
{"Student2":0591238,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":9213189},
{"Student3":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":0591238},
{"Student4":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":0294832},
{"Student5":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":0591823},
{"Student6":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":0501852}]
```

What I want:

```
[{"Student1":029182,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":029182},
{"Student2":0591238,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":029182},
{"Student3":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":029182},
{"Student4":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":9213189},
{"Student5":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":9213189},
{"Student6":9213189,"e-mail":"example@.com","studentnumber":9213189}]
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. I suggest edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I will try to make it clear.

Comment: For the first case (`<= 20`) use same code as `<= 60`, just don't increment the id (`ID += 1`).

Comment: Yes, but there are 20 students. For the first 3 I need the same studentnumbers from 4 to 6 other etc..

Comment: Then your example of what you want is incomplete.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code is missing some variable definitions and a main program.  The code includes `try -- except` blocks that don't seem to help the desired result.

Comment: It appears that you're trying to program beyond your comfort level in several directions at once.  I recommend incremental programming: start simply, add 2-5 lines of code at a time, and don't continue until you have tested those lines.  At the moment, you have outstanding issues with `try`, `dict`, and data movement.

Comment: @Prune, well the thing is I cant copy paste everything that I have done. There is sensitive information and that is why I maybe missed something to include. Im trying to include everything but I see that I missed to clarify 1/2 things. Everything in my program is running..

Comment: The code you posted is not running.  There are several syntax and semantic errors.

Comment: @Prune, maybe it works now? Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the code below can help. I have to figure it out that you can not use int number like 025. So I change it to strings.

```py
# student numbers
studentNunbers = [{"studentnumber": '029182', "ID": 0}, {"studentnumber": '0591238',"ID": 1},{"studentnumber": '9213189', "ID":2}]
# student
studentInfos = [{"Student1":'029182', "e-mail":'example@.com'}, {"Student2":'0591238',"e-mail":'example@.com'},
                {"Student3":'9213189',"e-mail":'example@.com'}, {"Student3":'92189',"e-mail":'example@.com'},
                {"Student2":'0538',"e-mail":'example@.com'}, {"Student2":'238',"e-mail":'example@.com'},
                {"Student2":'0598',"e-mail":'example@.com'}, {"Student2":'08',"e-mail":'example@.com'},]

students = [list(data.values())[0] for data in studentNunbers]

def merge(numRep=1):
    key = "studentnumber"
    stNumberIndex = 0
    iterInd = numRep
    for i in range(len(studentInfos)):
        value = studentNunbers[stNumberIndex][key]
        studentInfos[i][key] = value

        iterInd -= 1
        if iterInd == 0:
            iterInd = numRep
            stNumberIndex += 1

def test():
    if len(studentNunbers) < 20:
        merge(numRep=3)

    elif len(studentNunbers) < 60:
        merge(numRep=1)
    else:
        pass

test()
print(studentInfos)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is something that I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help, but I do spend most of my time in understanding your purpose.

Comment: Hahha, sorry.. for the next question I will take a deep breath before explaining my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to conditionally update a list of dicts.

**Given**

```
import random


students = [
    {"Student1": "029182", "e-mail": "ex@mail.com"},
    {"Student2": "0591238", "e-mail": "ex@mail.com"},
    {"Student3": "9213189", "e-mail": "ex@mail.com"},
]
```

**Code**

```
def get_unique_numbers(size=10):
    """Return an a list of unique random values."""
    return random.sample(range(10000, 99999), size)


def update(students):
    """Return a list of updated dicts."""
    n = len(students)

    # Conditionally, generate student numbers
    if n <= 20:
        student_numbers = [students[0]["Student1"]] * n
    elif 20 < n <= 60:
        student_numbers = get_unique_numbers(n)

    # Update dicts w/student numbers
    return [{**d, "student_num": n} for d, n in zip(students, student_numbers)]
```

**Demo**

A small list of students (`n <= 20`) returns dicts with the same student number:

```
update(students)
# [{'Student1': '029182', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': '029182'},
#  {'Student2': '0591238', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': '029182'},
#  {'Student3': '9213189', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': '029182'}]
```

A larger list (`n > 20`) returns dicts with random student numbers*:

```
update(students * 7)
# {'Student1': '029182', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 28308},
# {'Student2': '0591238', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 21986},
# {'Student3': '9213189', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 36603},
# ...
# {'Student1': '029182', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 38362},
# {'Student2': '0591238', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 99305},
# {'Student3': '9213189', 'e-mail': 'ex@mail.com', 'student_num': 78360}
```

<sup>*Note: implement the random number generator however you wish.  This one returns random integers from a sample population.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like using dictionaries, I just think a class object is much more convenient, although maybe slower in large scale.

I'm not sure what your issue is, I'm not aware that there can't be two same valued things in a dictionary.

here is how I would do it

```
import random as r

class student():
    def __init__(self,ID,numb):
        self.number = ID
        self.email = 'example@mail.com'
        self.name = 'student{}'.format(numb)

students = []
for i in range(60):
    x = student(r.randint(10000,99999),i)
    students.append(x)
def test():
    ID = 0
    for i in list(students):
        print(i.name,i.number,i.email)

test()
```

if you want to set the student number just change the r.randint bit

hope it helps if you have to use a dictionary
or if you have any problem please ask :)